# Comparing values in a list of dataframes to another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I am stuck in the following problem. I have `df_input` as my input data frame which contains only 1 column called Site_Sector. Site_Sector has the following structure:

```
 Site_Sector
--------------
  DEP_1234
  TRE_5421
  YUT_0901
  IOP_ABC3
  POS_3456
  MEC_2341
  XAZ_4532
  QPI_9012
  KPI_1200
  LPO_1300
  KIN_9012
  SVP_0001
  ....
  JOP_1289
```

I have 3 data frames called df_cr, df_gt and df_ba which are contained in a list, `list_of_dfs = [df_cr,df_gt,df_ba]`. They have the following structure (I will type down only two data frame):

```
 #let's consider some data of df_cr as example

 |  Date     |   Site    | Sector   |  KPI_1   | QA_value | Active |
 | --------- |---------- |----------|----------|----------| ------ |
  09/12/2015     CR_XAZ    XAZ_4532     50.0        100.0       Y
  09/12/2015     CR_PET    PET_2312     50.0        100.0       Y   
  09/13/2015     CR_XAZ    XAZ_4532     50.0        100.0       Y
  09/13/2015     CR_PET    PET_2312     50.0        100.0       Y
  09/14/2015     CR_XAZ    XAZ_4532     30.0        60.0        Y
  09/14/2015     CR_PET    PET_2312     25.0        50.0        N
  09/15/2015     CR_XAZ    XAZ_4532     25.0        50.0        N
  09/15/2015     CR_PET    PET_2312     40.0        80.0        Y
  09/16/2015     CR_XAZ    XAZ_4532     35.0        70.0        Y
  09/16/2015     CR_PET    PET_2312     45.0        90.0        Y
  09/17/2015     CR_XAZ    XAZ_4532     15.0        30.0        N
  09/17/2015     CR_PET    PET_2312     50.0        100.0       Y
    .....
  09/25/2015     CR_XAZ    PET_4532     12.0        24.0        N
  09/25/2015     CR_PET    XAZ_2312     12.0        24.0        N

 #let's consider some data of df_ba as example

 |  Date     |   Site   | Sector   |  KPI_1   | QA_value | Active |
 | --------- |--------- |----------| ---------|----------| ------ |
  09/12/2015     CR_DEP   DEP_1234     35.0        70.0        Y
  09/12/2015     CR_XZT   XZT_1212     50.0        100.0       Y   
  09/13/2015     CR_DEP   DEP_1234     15.0        30.0        N
  09/13/2015     CR_XZT   XZT_1212     50.0        100.0       Y
  09/14/2015     CR_DEP   DEP_1234     35.0        70.0        Y
  09/14/2015     CR_XZT   XZT_1212     25.0        50.0        Y
  09/15/2015     CR_DEP   DEP_1234     25.0        50.0        Y
  09/15/2015     CR_XZT   XZT_1212     40.0        80.0        Y
  09/16/2015     CR_DEP   DEP_1234     15.0        30.0        N
  09/16/2015     CR_XZT   XZT_1212     45.0        90.0        Y
  09/17/2015     CR_DEP   DEP_1234     50.0        100.0       Y
  09/17/2015     CR_XZT   XZT_1212     50.0        100.0       Y
    .....
  09/25/2015     CR_DEP   DEP_1234     10.0        20.0        N
  09/25/2015     CR_XZT   XZT_1212     50.0        100.0       Y
```

My goal is to **compare each value of the Site_Sector column data frame against each of the Sector columns of each data frame that is contained in the list**. If there is a match between Site_Sector and Sector columns then add the columns Date, KPI_1, QA_value and Active into the df_input data frame.

```
 #expected output

 Site_Sector|  Date     | KPI_1| QA_value | Active 
----------------------------------------------------
  DEP_1234   09/12/2015   35.0    70.0        Y
  DEP_1234   09/13/2015   15.0    30.0        N
  DEP_1234   09/14/2015   35.0    70.0        Y
  DEP_1234   09/15/2015   25.0    50.0        N
   ....
  XAZ_4532   09/12/2015   50.0    100.0       Y
  XAZ_4532   09/13/2015   50.0    100.0       Y
  XAZ_4532   09/14/2015   30.0    60.0        Y
  XAZ_4532   09/15/2015   25.0    50.0        N
   ....
```

If something was not clear or more details are needed please comment on this post and I will be glad to explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this with a *list comprehension* + `pd.Series.isin`:

```
data = df_input.Site_Sector
filtered_dfs = [x[x.Sector.isin(data)] for x in list_of_dfs]
output = pd.concat(filtered_dfs).drop('Site', 1)
```

---

For your input, this is what you get:

```
print(output.sort_values('Sector'))
          Date    Sector  KPI_1  QA_value Active
0   09/12/2015  DEP_1234   35.0      70.0      Y
2   09/13/2015  DEP_1234   15.0      30.0      N
4   09/14/2015  DEP_1234   35.0      70.0      Y
6   09/15/2015  DEP_1234   25.0      50.0      Y
8   09/16/2015  DEP_1234   15.0      30.0      N
10  09/17/2015  DEP_1234   50.0     100.0      Y
12  09/25/2015  DEP_1234   10.0      20.0      N
0   09/12/2015  XAZ_4532   50.0     100.0      Y
2   09/13/2015  XAZ_4532   50.0     100.0      Y
4   09/14/2015  XAZ_4532   30.0      60.0      Y
6   09/15/2015  XAZ_4532   25.0      50.0      N
8   09/16/2015  XAZ_4532   35.0      70.0      Y
10  09/17/2015  XAZ_4532   15.0      30.0      N
```

Comment: Yeah!  Much cleaner this way.